# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException when 2nd value is absent in JSON Parsing

Tags: android

I am getting ArrayoutofBound Exception below:

```
Process: com.lifeontrack, PID: 1379
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
   at com.lifeontrack.fragment.caregiver.ViewCaregiverFragment$3.onResponse(ViewCaregiverFragment.java:154)
   at com.lifeontrack.fragment.caregiver.ViewCaregiverFragment$3.onResponse(ViewCaregiverFragment.java:126)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Code:

```
String numberone = "";
String numbertwo = "";

JSONArray phoneArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("phone");
JSONObject cit = phoneArray.getJSONObject(0);
String phoneNumbers = "";
for (int count=1; count <= phoneArray.length(); count++)
{
    if (phoneNumbers.length() == 0)
        phoneNumbers += phoneArray.getJSONObject(count-1).getString("value");
    else
        phoneNumbers += ","+ phoneArray.getJSONObject(count-1).getString("value");
}

System.out.println("Phonenumbers" + phoneNumbers);
String[] numbers = phoneNumbers.split(",");
numberone = numbers[0];
numbertwo = numbers[1];

View.setText(numberone);
View.setText(numbertwo);

Button btn_home_phone_viewCg = ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_phone_viewCg));
btn_home_phone_viewCg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!Objects.equals(numberone, "")){
            Uri numberoneuri = Uri.parse("tel:"+numberone);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberoneuri);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }
});

Button btn_home_phone_viewCgtwo = ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_phone_viewCgtwo));
btn_home_phone_viewCgtwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!Objects.equals(numbertwo, "")){
            Uri numbertwouri = Uri.parse("tel:"+numbertwo);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numbertwouri);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }
});
```

When code runs output : `Phonenumbers : 9784513234,9487516132`
When code breaks output : `Phonenumbers : 9784513234,`

I believe it is happening when String "numbertwo" has no value while, could that be possibility? if yes how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Check the response you are getting in json, bcoz w.r.t the code it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake.

```
if(numbers.length > 0){
    numberone = numbers[0];
}

if(numbers.length > 1){
    numbertwo = numbers[1];
}
```

**Explanation:**

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` fires when you try to access value at the position out of the range of array.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you should take phonenumber as a string or array because in JSON parsing ',' read and it considers next number as a JSON object.
phone number should like:

`phonenumber: {'onenumber','secondnumber'}`

Answer (score 0):

Will solve ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

```
JSONArray phoneArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("phone");
    //loop your jsaonArray
    for(int count=0; count<phoneArray.length(); count++){
        JSONObject cit = phoneArray.getJSONObject(count);
        //do your stuff here
    }
```